# Fancybox (v1.3.1) showActivity() shows inconsistently in Chrome/Safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, webkit, fancybox

I'm using the following call for fancybox: $.fancybox.showActivity(); to display the loading animation.  It works in firefox and IE.  Chrome and Safari, however, are being very inconsistent.  So to test if there was a problem with the call, I created a button and attached the call via a JS function.  When I click the button (to verify the call works on it's own) and then press the button that's actually what I'm coding it, then it works.  But if I don't press the (verification test) button, and only press the actual code button, then it doesn't show.  I can see the  div in the debugger as well.  Do any reasons come to mind for this inconsistent functionality?

Code Snippets:

Verification Test button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="checkFancybox();">Check Fancybox</button>            
<script>
function checkFancybox(){
$.fancybox.showActivity();
alert("Fancybox call completed.");
}
</script>
```

Actual Coding button:

```
<form id="video-upload-form" action="{url}?nexturl={nextUrl}" 
      method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input name="file" type="file"/>
<input name="token" type="hidden" value=""/>
<input value="Upload Video File" type="button" name="submitVideoUpload" 
       onClick="checkFile()" class="button" />
</form>
<script> 
 function checkFile(){
    //RegEx for valid file name and extensions.
    var fileVal = document.forms["video-upload-form"].elements['file'].value;

    if(fileVal != ""){
      //notify user of activity
      $.fancybox.showActivity();
      document.getElementById('vintro-upload-form').submit();
    }else{alert('Please select the Video file.');}
 }
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be correct ... if you hook the js functions in HTML you better use

```
<input value="Upload Video File" type="button" name="submitVideoUpload" 
   onClick="javascript:checkFile();" class="button" />
```

The "javascript:;" is important. This way you can be sure it works x-browser.

Other then that you might wanna try it this way:

```
<input id="mybutton" value="Upload Video File" type="button" name="submitVideoUpload" class="button" />
<script>
// Once the DOM is ready
$(function(){
    // bind your function
    $("#mybutton").click(function(){ checkFile(); });
});

// define your function
function checkFile(){
    //RegEx for valid file name and extensions.
    var fileVal = document.forms["video-upload-form"].elements['file'].value;

    if(fileVal != ""){
        //notify user of activity
        $.fancybox.showActivity();
        document.getElementById('vintro-upload-form').submit();
    }
    else { alert('Please select the Video file.'); }
}
</script>
```

Bind the click handler when the DOM has loaded. This way the handler can be hooked when it actually finds the HTML to hook it to.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but that didn't help me either.  I think there's a difference in how webkit deals with submits vs how Firefox and IE do.  And that's what is causing the issue.  I determined this by commenting out the submit line after the fancybox call, and my fancybox showed activity without a problem.

Comment: So it works on my localhost, but not on the development server.  What could I be missing here?

Comment: It sounds like a loading issue. If you use your developer toolbar (Firebug, IE Toolbar, ...) do you get bad requests (Net tab, network tab) on the prd server? Do you load jquery framework from google code? What is the order of loading those scripts? 1->external CSS 2->jquery.min.js 3->yourfunctions.js 4->yourdomreadyscripts.js

Comment: any javascript errors (enable console in firebug)? This may prevent you from running code aswell

Comment: There was a DOMEception, error code 12 that was the issue.  I went ahead and just put an animated gif inside of a hidden <DIV> that is revealed when the user's video is being uploaded.  No javascript errors.